# Error with Nullable annotation when generating Javadoc using doclava

Tags: android-studio, javadoc, nullable

I am trying to generate a Javadoc for an Android Library using Doclava in Android Studio. The source code uses "Nullable" tag at some point and this causes a crash while generating the javadoc:

> In doclet class com.google.doclava.Doclava,  method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.annotation.Nullable not found

Can I somehow overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to include in Javadoc's classpath, the findbugs:jsr305 library.

So, in my Gradle configuration, I added:

```
dependencies {

    // For Doclava JavaDoc
    jaxDoclet("com.google.doclava:doclava:1.0.6")
    classpaths files('build/intermediates/classes/release')
    classpaths 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
     //.... the rest of the configuration
     options {
         classpath += configurations.classpaths.files.asType(List)
         //.... the rest of the configuration
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this exception, check here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1261

Just add `-XDignore.symbol.file` to the end of the command, and it may remove this exception.